# Replacing Column row values if it contains a string or character in R

Tags: r, replace

I am currently trying to change gender values in a dataframe column for consistency. 
I currently have the following code, but it does not change any of the row values. It prints 'male' consistently for every value, but it does not update in the dataframe.

```
count <- 0
for(i in mySubset$Gender){
  count = count + 1
  if('Male' %in% i){
    mySubset$Gender[count] <- 'male'
    print(mySubset$Gender[count])
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show sample data and desired output?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're asking, but it sounds like you're trying to replace any time you see 'male' in a column with something else?

If so..you could do it this way:

```
 dataframe$gender[which(dataframe$gender=="Male")] <- "NewValue"
```

It would be better to have an example though.